# Combining Two Address Fields in SSRS w/ Expression

Tags: ssrs-2008, ssrs-expression

I'm trying to combine two fields into one text box in SSRS through an expression. If an address does have two entries, I'd like a line break between Addr1 and Addr2.

What I have currently is:

```
=Fields!Addr1.Value & VbCRLF &
Fields!Addr2.Value
```

But Addr2 may not have an entry so I'd like to be able to handle NULLS effectively.

I've tried:

```
=Fields!Addr1.Value & VbCRLF &
IIF(IsNothing(Fields!Addr2.Value),"",Fields!Addr2.Value
```

But that doesn't seem to work.  Any suggestions on how to handle this?

Comment: Thank you, that works. Can't mark your comment as the correct answer, but that was it.

Comment: Converted my comment to an answer, since that was it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you just need to change the order of your conditional concatenation:

```
=Fields!Addr1.Value & IIF(IsNothing(Fields!Addr2.Value),"",VbCRLF & Fields!Addr2.Value)
```

(I think you intended the VbCRLF to be conditional.)